Why my transparent mesh has those artifacts?
I have transparent mesh for a game, when I export it it gets coveted to triangles and had those artifacts on it, I checked face orientation and it's fine. I don't know what wrong.




can you post the wireframe?

@JohnCheathem I updated my question with picture, it made of single faces

this might help.. the alpha hashed setting might exist in your game engine shader. you can also try turning off back face culling. [link] (https://i.imgur.com/3pQTCpw.jpeg)

this might not be practical for you, but this helps for me. link
Clear custom normals, smooth by angle, and separate by loose parts.

@JohnCheathem Awesome tnx solved
